# Trace of second-order tensor and its invariance under coordinate transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, covariance, trace

Let's consider an arbitrary scalar field. If I act twice on the scalar field with a gradient operator, I will obtain second-order tensor. If I will take a trace of this tensor, I will obtain another scalar field. Is the resulting scalar field invariant under coordinate transformation? For example, if I will do the same operation in spherical coordinates, do I obtain the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The trace of a tensor is one of its [invarients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors), so the trace will remain constant no matter which coordinate representation you use.

Here's a proof from the mathematics stack exchange that the [characteristic polynomial of a matrix is independent from your choice of basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274092/characteristic-polynomial-independent-from-the-choice-of-basis).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't it proofed just for linear transformations? transformation from cartesian to spherical coordinates is non-linear.

Comment: You can't take the gradient of a gradient. You can however take the divergence of a gradient which gives you the Laplacian. A tensor can be viewed as a linear or multi-linear mapping.

Comment: Thus what is that? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-gradient-of-a-vector-field

Comment: @Tomek the coordinate transformation can be nonlinear but tensors transform linearly at each point according to the Jacobian (and inverse Jacobian) of the nonlinear transformation.

Comment: Note: You can take the gradient of the gradient (and mathematicians call the result the Hessian). In general, the gradient of the vector is a 2-tensor: A common notation is $\nabla \circ \vec \phi$, to make clear that you don't mean the divergence. In components its $(\nabla \circ \vec \phi)_{ij} = \partial_i \phi_j$. Of course, you are free to argue, that you don't call that object the gradient, but there are those who do.